# How to refresh resources in Node without restarting the server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, koa

I'm using koa-static-folder, but apparently it doesn't provide access to files added after the server starts without the need to restart the actual server. Are there any middleware or libraries that do?

Answer (score 0):

As it says [in the description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-static-folder) of `koa-static-folder`

> changes made in the underlying folders require a restart of your app

You can use [nodemon](http://nodemon.io/) to restart your when files change.

Comment: I know this, but what I need is a way to refresh the resources without restarting the server, be it another library or the like